# S-expression comments in Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp

I have written a Common Lisp implementation of Scheme's s-expression comments ([SRFI 62](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-62/srfi-62.html)):

```lisp
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel
            :load-toplevel
            :execute)

  (defun handle-s-expression-comment (stream char n)
    (declare (ignore char))
    (when n
      (error "Infix parameter not allowed in s-expression comment."))
    (read stream)  ; Discard the next s-expression.
    (values))

  (set-dispatch-macro-character #\# #\; #'handle-s-expression-comment))
```

With s-expression comments:

- `(+ 1 #;(* 2 3) 4)` returns `5`
- `(list 'x #;'y 'z)` returns `(x z)`
- `(* 3 4 #;(+ 5 6))` returns `12`
- `(#;sqrt abs -123)` returns `123`

Is my implementation correct? What improvements can I make?

Comment: `(read stream)` should be `(read stream t nil t)` instead. Refer to: [read's recursive-p argument when used inside a reader macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69248229/reads-recursive-p-argument-when-used-inside-a-reader-macro).